# Android: Is it possible to easily get know that the view instance is actually visible on the screen?

Tags: android, android-view

Is it possible to easily get know that the view is actually visible on the screen. I mean the case when the view is a child of scrollview. Is there an easy way to get know when the view is scrolled out of the screen or scrolled into the visible screen area?
(or maybe there is other pattern for handling situation of "lazy initialisation" of views? - the listview rather wouldn't match while scrollview's children are variable types)
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is protected method [onDisplayHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDisplayHint%28int%29)

Comment: i mark it useful, however it does not solve the problem as in this method's documentation you can read `Applications should not rely on this hint as there is no guarantee that they will receive one`

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `onVisibilityChanged` event handler to the child views. This is called when the visibility of the view changes. Android documentation on this can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onVisibilityChanged%28android.view.View,%20int%29).

Comment: Are you sure it concerns the actual visibility not the visibilty property (which you set by `setVisibility`) ?